# SDL2 keypresses over SSH

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, sdl-2

I have an SDL2 application that I launch over SSH and I would like to have it process text input over the SSH connection. Is it possible to have the SSH connection show up as SDL_TEXTINPUT?

Additional Details / Requirements:

- I'm open to alternate solutions. This just seemed like it could be an easier option than trying to create a multi-threaded application to monitor stdin (I'm kind of a beginner with c++...)
- The idea is to use the text input to issue commands to cycle through states and interact with hardware (UART) connected to the remote system.
- The remote system is *essentially* a headless raspberry pi (SDL renderer pixels are memory mapped to /dev/fb1 for display)
- A keyboard can be directly connected to the remote system for input, but there is no console display which makes launching the application and printing debug messages problematic.
- I'm writing this in c++

Comment: https://blog.robertelder.org/detect-keyup-event-linux-terminal/

Comment: @genpfault I'm not looking for a keyup event. Are you trying to imply that SDL_TEXTINPUT can't function without keyup events?